# Symfony "Could not load type" service yaml

Tags: forms, symfony

I tried to create a service in Symfony 2.2 for one of my form :

service.yml:

```
tyg_user.settings.form:
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    factory_method: createNamed
    factory_service: form.factory
    arguments: 
        - tyg_user_settings
        - tyg_user_settings_name
tyg_user.settings.form.type:
    class: TyG\UserBundle\Form\Settings\SettingsFormType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: tyg_user_settings }
tyg_user.settings.form.handler:
    class: TyG\UserBundle\Form\Settings\SettingsFormHandler
    scope: request
    arguments:
        - @tyg_user.settings.form
        - @request
        - @fos_user.user_manager
```

SettingsForm.php

```
<?php

namespace TyG\UserBundle\Form\Settings;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface as FormBuilder;;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class SettingsForm extends AbstractType
{

  public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
  {
      $builder
        ->add('birthday', 'birthday')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('showmail')
        ->add('showbirthday')
      ;
  }

  public function getName()
  {
      return 'tyg_user_settings';
  }
}
?>
```

But an error occuered :

```
Could not load type "tyg_user_settings_name
```

This occurs when I get my form through the service container :

```
$this->container->get('tyg_user.settings.form');
```

I used to do create my service through the xml format but when I change to the yml format I can't figure out how to to make it works

Answer (score 2):

The `tyg_user_settings_name` is referencing a form type alias.

If you are wanting it to reference a parameter you should use `%tyg_user_settings_name%` instead.

Comment: When I use xml format I didn't have to reference a parameter. Why in yaml formt I should ?

Comment: With `createNamed` the factory_method is `createNamed($name, $type = 'form'...etc`, the first argument being the name. If you don't want to name it then you should just use `create` instead. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php , lines 37 and 45 for `create` and `createNamed`, respectively.

Comment: Actually I juste change my symfony version from 2.0 to 2.2 and createNamed parameters change so I just have to swap my argument :)